# Find a tuple in a list of tuples and add if not present

Tags: python, list, tuples, undirected-graph

There is an undirected graph with a list of tuples where each element is a tuple in the form of (id1,id2). I have to find whether a new (s,t) is present in the list of tuples which contains all the edges and add the tuple if it is not present. edges is the list of tuples

```
def add_edge(s: str, t: str) -> None:
       
        if (s,t) or (t,s) not in edges:
            edges.append((s,t))
        return edges
```

But this fails in acoounting for duplicates of the form (a,b) = (b,a)

Comment: `(s,t) not in edges and (t,s) not in edges`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will work well

```
def add_edge(s: str, t: str) -> None:
       
        if (s,t) not in edge and (t,s) not in edges:
            edges.append((s,t))
        return edges
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s,t) or (t,s) not in edges
```

This is not doing what you think.  `(s,t)` is treated as a separate condition all on its own.  So the statement is really this:

```
(s,t)
or
(t,s) not in edges
```

And since `(s,t)` is a non-empty sequence, the entire statement is automatically true.

Comment: Add how to fix it :)